# How do I construct static variables with a for loop and store them in a static array?

Tags: rust

I need static variables (or any variables associated with a module/file) and a static array to hold them in the same module. It's not necessary for them to point to the same memory. The static variables need a loop to initialize. Is this possible in Rust?

In code, it would look something like below.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub struct A {
    char_lens: HashSet<u8>,
}

impl A {
    pub(crate) fn new(s: &'static str) -> A {
        let mut char_lens: HashSet<u8> = HashSet::new();
        for s in s.split_whitespace() {
            char_lens.insert(s.len() as u8);
        }
        A { char_lens }
    }
}

static VAR_A1: A = A::new("some string 1");
static VAR_A2: A = A::new("some string 2");

static A_ARRAY: [A; 2] = [VAR_A1, VAR_A2];
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba8b9da8eb45d92617ea4bf27fb53aaa)

The code above fails because the static variables cannot use a loop to initialize themselves:

```
error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
  --> src/lib.rs:17:20
   |
17 | static VAR_A1: A = A::new("some string 1");
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I attempted using the lazy_static crate:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub struct A {
    char_lens: HashSet<u8>,
}

impl A {
    pub(crate) fn new(s: &'static str) -> A {
        let mut char_lens: HashSet<u8> = HashSet::new();
        for s in s.split_whitespace() {
            char_lens.insert(s.len() as u8);
        }
        A { char_lens }
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref VAR_A1: A = A::new("some string 1");
    static ref VAR_A2: A = A::new("some string 2");
    static ref A_ARRAY: [A; 2] = [VAR_A1, VAR_A2];
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bbf83790941416ca8a184dbae047b88f)

This now fails because lazy_static generates a unique struct under the hood for static variables. Now `VAR_A1` and `VAR_A2` have different types, and there is no way to reference the types for the array.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:21:35
   |
21 |     static ref A_ARRAY: [A; 2] = [VAR_A1, VAR_A2];
   |                                   ^^^^^^ expected struct `A`, found struct `VAR_A1`
```

Comment: Do you **need** `A1` and `A2` as separate variables?

Comment: @Shepmaster What do you mean by **need**? They represent two separate things.

Comment: I mean: would it be acceptable to have **only** the array containing the values, without defining `A1` / `A2`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I need the variables and the array containing the variables. It's not necessary for them to point to the same memory.

Comment: What prevents you from cloning / copying them?

Comment: Your current code _cannot_ work because `[VAR_A1, VAR_A2]` would transfer ownership of `VAR_A1` out of its variable and into the array, leaving the variable in an undefined state.

Comment: Does using `[VAR_A1.clone(), VAR_A2.clone()]` with `lazy_static` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with a reference, just take a reference and use deref coercion:

```
static ref A_ARRAY: [&'static A; 2] = [&VAR_A1, &VAR_A2];
```

<sup>Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bee75c90fef228898a737ae08aa89528</sup>

---

If you need an owned value, you can use `.clone()`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)] // For this method, we need to be able to clone.
pub struct A {
    char_lens: HashSet<u8>,
}

// ...

static ref A_ARRAY: [A; 2] = [VAR_A1.clone(), VAR_A2.clone()];
```

<sup>Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3d48026b379e1fc3412d3f0af52286e4</sup>

Comment: Oh, I see, `std::ops::Deref` is in scope within the `lazy_static!` macro. Interesting.